# How to set compiler-specific flags with autotools

Tags: gcc, clang, autotools, compiler-options

We use autotools as our build infrastructure, and we use clang and gcc as compilers. Recently we hit a gcc warning that needed

```
--param max-vartrack-size=100000000
```

to silence (without completey disabling gcc's vartracking). Clang doesn't accept that option and produces

```
argument unused during compilation: '--param max-vartrack-size=100000000'
```

To silence that, clang needs

```
-Qunused-arguments
```

and that produces an error under gcc:

```
unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
```

1. What is the best way to define compiler-specific flags in `configure.ac`, after a compiler has been selected with, e.g. `AC_PROG_CXX`? We `AC_SUBST(AM_CXXFLAGS)` so I guess I'd be expanding a compiler specific variable within `AM_CXXFLAGS`.
2. What is the right way to enable a per-target option in a `Makefile.am` for just one compiler? I'm thinking of:

   ```
   if HAVE_GCC
       SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS = --param...
   endif
   if HAVE_CLANG
       SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS = -Q...
   endif
   libfoo_la_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS)
   ```

but I'd need the `HAVE_*` vars subst'ed from configure.ac. Do `AC_PROG_CXX/CC` perhaps already define something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AM_CXXFLAGS` isn't something you should `AC_SUBST`. It is reserved for use by automake. If you look at the `Makefile` generated for a C++ target, you will find definitions for `CXXCOMPILE` and `LTCXXCOMPILE`, which always include the `AM_CXXFLAGS` variable.

You want to add the (conditional) compiler flag to `AM_CXXFLAGS` or to `libfoo_la_CXXFLAGS`. The former will affect all C++ compilations, and the latter just the per-library compilations. So it's just a matter of getting `SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS` right in `configure.ac`.

```
AC_PROG_CXX
...
FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS=;
if `$CXX -v 2>&1 | grep 'gcc version' >/dev/null 2>&1` ; then
  FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS="--param max-vartrack-size=100000000"
fi

AC_SUBST(FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS, $FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS)
```

The `GXX` test is insufficient as autoconf just tests for the `__GNUC__` macro (AFAIK), so clang++ will set: `GXX=yes`

The problem is, there isn't a portable way of detecting command line options that are unknown. Intel's `icc -v` will even reproduce the `gcc version` string. So you might have to add another filter, like: `| grep -v 'icc'`

You could optionally check that the flag works as advertised before `AC_SUBST`, but this doesn't really help if the compiler only generates a warning:

```
saved_CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS"
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS $FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS"

AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([])],,[FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS=;])
AC_LANG_POP([C++])
CXXFLAGS="$saved_CXXFLAGS"
```

Then in `Makefile.am`:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = $(FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS)
```

or:

```
libfoo_la_CXXFLAGS = $(FOO_SPECIFIC_CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: I'm puzzled by your statement that one should not `AC_SUBST` `AM_CXXFLAGS`. How is that different from setting `AM_CXXFLAGS` in all of the 15ish `Makefile.am`s by hand? `AC_SUBST`ing `AM_CXXFLAGS` is the perfect solution for things like enabling warnings for the whole project by default, or choosing the older ABI with gcc 5.1 (which needs to be the same for all objects). How else would I achieve this, short of setting `AM_CXXFLAGS` in each of the `Makefile.am`s?

Comment: I opted to add two `AM_CONDITIONAL`s to my configure.ac, `HAVE_GCC` and `HAVE_CLANG` with the conditional test equivalent to your `grep` check. Thanks!

Comment: @Irfy - that's what `CXXFLAGS` is for. You can pass compiler specific flags to `configure` via `CXXFLAGS`, or add / modify `CXXFLAGS` flags in `configure.ac`. This variable is also included in the C++ build rules.

Answer (score 1):

If some flag produces an error  it is easy to write an m4 macro to detect if the compiler supports this flag.

Check ax_check_compile_flag from the autoconf archive.

Comment: I'm sure this is the *right* way to do it, but since it's an internal project, not distributed, I opted for the simplest thing possible, which turned out to be two `AM_CONDITIONAL`s.